# Is $a$ < $b$ if $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous in $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous in $[a,b]$.

In theory $a$ can be equal to $b$. But then if $f(x)$ is defined on one point it's not differentiable because by definition derivative is the rate of change between 2 points on an interval.

By conventional notation we write the left-most coordinate of an interval adjacent to the left bracket and the right-most coordinate of the interval adjacent to the right bracket which in such case would mean that $a$ is before $b$.

So can we claim that $a<b$?

Or maybe if given $(a,b)$ the convention pre-supposes that $a \neq b$?

Comment: By definition, $(a,b) = \{x: a\lt x\lt b\}$. Therefore, if $(a,b)$ is not empty $a\lt b$.

Comment: @JohnDouma It's $a <b$ if $(a,b)$ is nonempty and $a = b$ if $(a,b)$ is empty. Thus, the final relation becomes $a \leq b$ since the statements still hold if $(a,b)$ are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion (and these three words imply that this is just some very subjective thinking) it depends on how you define differentiability. If your definition of differentiability requires $f$ to be defined on an open interval (an interval of the form $(a,b)$ with $a<b$), then you are right, because then if $f$ is defined only on a set $[a,a]=\{a\}$ with one point, talking about differentiability of $f$ doesn't make any sense (because for this case it is not defined, and - as you have pointed out already - cannot tell anything about the rate of change, cause $f$ cannot change anyhow since there is only one value at which $f$ is defined).

However, it is sometimes convenient to define differentiability for those functions by just *defining* them to be differentiable (From a logical point of view this also makes sense and guides you sooner or later to the question how statements about the empty set are handled, see the comments above). This is, at first glance, pure convention. That way, one can replace a statement like "Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ $\color{red}{\text{for }a<b}$ be continuous and differentiable in $(a,b)$ such that ..." by something like "Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be continuous and differentiable in $(a,b)$ such that ...". The second statement is easier to read because there are no redundant information. But as you can see, it is only a matter of taste.

Let's take a closer look at the definition of differentiability. What does
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\quad\text{exists}
\end{align*}
really mean? It means that for each sequence of numbers $(x_n)$ contained in the domain of definition of $f$ and so that $x_n\neq x_0$ for each $n$, the limit
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_0)}{x_n-x_0}
\end{align*}
exists and is the same, no matter how the sequence $(x_n)$ actually looks like. Thus, $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, if this works for each such sequence. But if there is no such sequence, then there is nothing to check, there is nothing that can go wrong, so, well, then we say, $f$ is indeed differentiable. But, again, this is our choice. We also could say, that $f$ is not differentiable in this case, and we are again talking about empty sets and how to treat them.

From a porgrammers point of view: Imagine that you would like to write a program that checks whether all elements of a set of objects (a list) $L$ satisfy a given property $P$, say. Thus, your function yields `true`, if all elements of $L$ satisfy $P$, otherwise `false`. You probably know that functions (depends on the language) have to return something, in any case! So we would probably write our function like this:

```
bool function check(List L, Property P) {
   for each (x in L) {
       if (!P(x))
           return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

In your case, $P(x)=f$ is differentiable at $x$, and $L=(a,b)$. In case $L=\emptyset$, `check(L, P)` returns `true`. Try to rewrite this function so that it returns false if $L=\emptyset$. You would need a couple more lines. In summary, it is just handy to say that any property for elements of the empty set is true.
Again (see comments) from a logical point of view, this is the only reasonable way to go. If the statement "Each element of the empty set is red" was false, then its negation "There is one element of the empty set which is not red" had to be true, which is clearly impossible.

To avoid all those discussions, my former Analysis Prof. just defined intervals to contain at least two elements. But again, just definition/convention. To cite my former Algebra Prof.: "When it comes to mathematical definitions there is no true or false, just convenient or inconvenient."

Comment: Thanks for a really comprehensive answer! I guess I'd need to check with our calculus teacher so I know the convention for our class.

Comment: You're welcome. For any further questions, don't hesitate to drop me an email.

Answer (score -1):

Note that if $a=b$ then $(a,b)$ is an empty set thus "f has a derivative on $(a,b)$" is a true statement.

Thus, by convention of noting lower bound first we can only claim $a \leq b$.

EDIT:
About the derivative on empty set.
In logic, a statement is either true or its logical negation is true (which is the same as saying that the statement is false).

Now, the logical negation of "f has a derivative $\forall x \in \emptyset$" is "for atleast one $x \in \emptyset$ $f(x)$ has no derivative".

Since there are no points in the empty set, one can't find a point for which $f(x)$ has no derivative.  Thus logical negation is false, making our statement true.

Conclusion: "f has a derivative $\forall x \in \emptyset$".

Comment: But from derivative definition: $f'(x) = lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{x_0+h-x_0}$ if $x_0+h=x_0$ then you get $0$ in the denominator? Or by definition $h \to 0$ but here it's $h=0$

Comment: For every point $x$ in the empty set the $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ exists. The trick is: there are no points in the empty set.

Comment: Indeed, every proposition of the form $\forall x \in \emptyset, P(x)$ is true.

Comment: I suppose you mean that $P(x)$ is the derivative of the function? From which area of math does this fact come from that the derivative exists on empty sets?

Comment: You are missing the point. We are saying something along the lines of "All pigs with wings speak english." which is true since you can't give a counter example. Logic is the area of mathematics.

Comment: I don't get it. I would think that giving an example in which there's division by zero proves my claim. Unless there's some other definition of derivative which we didn't learn in class.

Comment: I expanded my post a little, maybe this will help.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics) indeed $a<b$. So I guess your answer is not correct.

Comment: I don't see how this wiki article relates to the conversation at hand. The point stands that the claims on f (continuous on $[a,b]$ and derivable on $(a,b)$) don't force any relation ($<$, $=$, or $>$) on $a$ and $b$. It's purely convention that enforces $a \leq b$.

Comment: Because the convention for empty sets according to the article is $(a,a)$.

Comment: This here is a technical point: it's okay to use convention as long as it doesn't change the results. Noting $[1,2]$ instead of $[2,1]$ is fine if we can just exchange $a$ for $b$ in all our statements and still get true statements. (say you assumed $a<b$ and it turns out $b<a$ then you just rewrite your proof by exchanging $a$ and $b$ and its fine.) Now assuming $a<b$ also assumes $a \neq b$ which can still be the case.